# Suspend automatically when no monitor is attached

Tags: suspend, hdmi

I use one HDMI cable for both the PC and the PS, and if I plug out the HDMI cable of the suspended PC, Ubuntu resumes.

Is there a way to suspend Ubuntu automatically if no HDMI cable is plugged in?

Comment: what do you mean by one hdmi cable? where is ubuntu installed ? and what is installed in pc?

Comment: Sorry, had a typo. Question now makes sense.

Comment: what does PS mean?

Comment: Playstation, but that should not be relevant for the question. It could be any HDMI device.